# Adjust shading of UITabBarItem

Tags: interface-builder, ipad, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a set of white images that I am currently using as the images for UITabBarItems in a UITabBar.

These images are shaded automatically, and I would like to adjust this shading so that the icons do not appear as dark as they do by default on the iPad.

I don't see anywhere to adjust the shading intensity in the nib file -- is there any way this can be adjusted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up creating another set of images.